# PCI-E USB Controller not Recognizing Legacy USB devices

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I recently installed a pci-e usb 3.0 controller that uses the VL805 chipset. I did this because I wanted to hook up an old arcadestick that only uses UHCI (which this card supports). After I installed the card using the drivers VIA provided, the joystick worked. This morning I booted up my PC and the joystick no longer worked even though I made no changes. My machine is running windows 10 n pro, and I have an Intel processor.

What could be causing this problem? How would I go about troubleshooting?

Comment: Automatic Windows 10 update maybe? Or your dog chew on USB cable... If it worked before, what else could it be?

Comment: No dogs, no automatic update either.

Comment: How about to re-install VIA driver? Or arcadestick driver?

Comment: I tried reinstalling the VIA driver, it didn't do anything. The arcadestick doesn't have a driver.

Comment: If the arcadestick does not have a special driver, then why do you need a special USB host card? LS/FS devices should be well supported by any USB controller if they conform to a standard USB class. If not, there must be a special driver.

Comment: It's a Playstation 3 arcade stick, a Madcatz TE-S. This arcade stick can work on PC, but only with legacy USB because the PCB they used in the stick only support UHCI. I have nvidia chipsets tend to have trouble with UHCI, after some googling I found out that the stick would work with a usb controller that used a VIA chipset.